# Understanding conditional operator and assignment in condition in code snippet

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how the third line in this code snippet (the assignment `value = f` in the condition of the conditional expression) is working:

```
someProp(propName, f) {
  let prop = this._props && this._props[propName], value
  if (prop != null && (value = f ? f(prop) : prop)) return value
  ...
}
```

In this example, `value` is undefined at the `console.log(value)` statement:

```
let f = 42;
value = f ? console.log('true') : console.log('false');
console.log(value);
```

It seems to me that the `value` variable returned on the third line of the first snippet would always be undefined. What am I missing? The snippet is from production code in an open source project I'm studying.

Also, `this._props` is an object. Why is the author using `if (prop != null && ...` to test if the props object exists, rather than just something like `if (prop && ...` ? And am I right in thinking that this is typical code of more experienced developers, or would others write it differently?

Comment: `value = f ? console.log('true') : console.log('false');` in this case `value` will always be `undefined` because it will be set to the return value of `console.log()` which is always `undefined`. `value = f ? f(prop) : prop)` in this case, if `f` is falsey, then `value = prop`, if `f`` is truthy (based on context, I suspect a callback), then `value` will be what is returned by `f(prop)`

Comment: Can you link the full code in the open source project you are studying?

Comment: @Bergi It's line 179 in [this file](https://github.com/ProseMirror/prosemirror-view/blob/master/src/index.js) from the ProseMirror project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional operator has a [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than the assignment operator, so this is parsed

```
if (prop != null && (value = (f ? f(prop) : prop))) return value
//                           ^                  ^
```

not

```
if (prop != null && ((value = f) ? f(prop) : prop)) return value
//                   ^         ^
```

as you were expecting. So yes, in your demo example you always get `undefined` as that's the return value of the `console.log` calls. But here it is assigned either `f(prop)` or `prop`.

> Also, why is the author using `prop != null && ...` rather than just `prop && ...`?

Because he likes being explicit.

> And am I right in thinking that this is typical code of more experienced developers?

No. Possibly typical code of developers that were once bitten by falsy values.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Bergi. I sincerely appreciate it. Am I correct in thinking it would be easy to trip on writing code like this myself, relying on operator precedence? Or is it pretty normal? I'm trying to improve my skills.

Comment: In general, yes it's pretty normal to rely on operator precedence - we do it every day when writing stuff like `1 + 2 * 3`. Admittedly, this one is a bit extreme (the whole function in the project you linked is, uh, *dense*), so just write explicit grouping operators when you are not sure. You will get more familiar with the precedence rules over time.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine this line:

```
if (prop != null && (value = f ? f(prop) : prop)) return value
```

Especially this part:

```
(value = f ? f(prop) : prop)
```

If `f` is truthy, set `value` to the return value of `f(prop)`.

If `f` is not thruthy, set `value` to the value of `prop`.

Value is then checked for thruthyness and returned.

---

In your second example:

```
let f = 42;
value = f ? console.log('true') : console.log('false');
console.log(value);
```

What you are actually doing is setting `value` to the return value of `console.log('true')` which is always going to be `undefined`, since `console.log()` returns `undefined`.

---

> And am I right in thinking that this is typical code of more experienced developers, or would others write it differently?

For easier understanding, and especially if the code is used in tutorials, I would personally expand the code for better readability among learners, but I also like my code compact, so if it was code for a library, I'd probably code along those lines too.

Comment: Thanks Luca, esp. for the comment on style

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think this is badly written; experience aside, it's too hard to read. Ternary inside an if condition which does an assignment which then may get returned - calm down.

Here it is longhand:

```
if ( prop != null ) {
    if ( f ) {
        value = f( prop );
    } else {
        value = prop;
    }
    if ( value ) return value;
}
```

An extra quirk is that `value` won't be returned if it's falsy, which (I guess) is why its assignment was part of the if condition. It is clever of the author to cram all this logic into one line but in my opinion it's better dumbed down.

Comment: no, the original code checks `value` with assigned value as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz could you explain that comment a little more? I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: you return the value of f(prop), and omit the check of `&& (value = f ? f(prop) : prop)`, where the value is checked and if not truthy, no return takes place.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yeah I missed that